# Prevent xxd from adding newline to the output

Tags: sed, xxd

On unix if I do

```
printf "aY.S'Hk([;jYJ}8eJ5)Wsd58/x}s]Pne3V-6:t@" | xxd -p -c 256
```

I get

```
61592e5327486b285b3b6a594a7d38654a352957736435382f787d735d50 
6e6533562d363a7440
```

However on mac os (which is what I want on linux as well)
I get

```
61592e5327486b285b3b6a594a7d38654a352957736435382f787d735d506e6533562d363a7440
```

I couldn't find any way to prevent `xxd` from adding a line break to hex output. I have tried `sed` to remove the line break but it doesn't work. I can't install `tr` on my unix machine. Is there any way I can create a hex output from my string that doesn't have any line break or whitespace or is there a way to configure `xxd` on linux to not add any whitespace? Note, I have tried pretty much all the options of `xxd` with no luck

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on "Unix". The manual says that the line will not be broken if you use `-p -s -c 0`. Does that help you? Not turning this into an answer because I can't reproduce your issue and I don't know whether this would help or not since there might be something else involved.

Comment: I can verify that I have the same issue as the questioner using Ubuntu. Using -p as well

Comment: "_I can't install tr on my unix machine_" - the `tr` utility should be part of the standard base installation. Not having it is an error. If you can't install it then ask the system administrators to do so on your behalf

Answer (score 2):

I tried this (macos ventura 13.4 (22F66), bash 5.2.15(1)-release):

```
$ echo -n "change this password to a secret" | xxd -p
6368616e676520746869732070617373776f726420746f20612073656372
6574
```

Then randomly tried (without a clue :);

```
$ echo -n "change this password to a secret" | xxd -p -c 0
6368616e676520746869732070617373776f726420746f206120736563726574
```

that was what i've been looking for. maybe this helps.

Comment: The action shouldn't have needed to be random as it's in the command documentation (see `man xxd`): "_**`-c cols`** | **`-cols cols`** Format <cols> octets per line. [...] With `-ps`, `0` results in one long line of output._"